# How do I use my own certificates as OPC UA client certificates in Java?

Tags: java, security, certificate, opc-ua

I have created certificates signed by a root certificate according to [this](https://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/) instruction and converted the .crt to a .der file as well as the .key to a .pem one. Now I want to use these to send along when my opc ua client connects to my server (TwinCAT Beckhoff on virtual machine). Until now I send certificates generated automatically by opc ua (see code below).

I tried several things (btw I'm rather new to everything...) but nothing seems to work, the certificates can not be accepted on the server side and/or not only my own certificates are sent but also the automatically generated ones.

This is my code for initialization with which I send certificates that are generated automatically. How do I have to change it to send my own ones along?

```
public void initialize() throws URISyntaxException, SecureIdentityException,
SessionActivationException, InitializationException, IOException {

    // IP + port of my local machine
    String serverUri = "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:4840";

    // configure the ua client
    try {
        UaClient client = new UaClient(serverUri);
    } catch (final URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new InitializationException("The server uri has an invalid syntax.", e);
    }
    // set validator and listener to deal with certificates
    final PkiFileBasedCertificateValidator validator = new PkiFileBasedCertificateValidator();
    client.setCertificateValidator(validator);
    final CertificateValidationListener validationListener = new CertificateValidationListener();
    validator.setValidationListener(validationListener);

    // create application description
    final ApplicationDescription appDescription = new ApplicationDescription();
    appDescription.setApplicationName(new LocalizedText("middlewareOpcUaClient", Locale.ENGLISH));
    appDescription.setApplicationUri("urn:localhost:UA:Middleware");
    appDescription.setProductUri("urn:xxx.Middleware");
    appDescription.setApplicationType(ApplicationType.Client);

    // create certificates
    // basically copied from the opc ua SampleConsoleClient
    final File privatePath = new File(validator.getBaseDir(), "private");
    final KeyPair issuerCertificate = null;
    final int[] keySizes = null;
    final ApplicationIdentity identity = ApplicationIdentity.loadOrCreateCertificate(appDescription, "Middleware", "opcua", privatePath, issuerCertificate, keySizes, true);

    client.setApplicationIdentity(identity);
    client.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

    // set timeouts
    client.setTimeout(30000);
    client.setStatusCheckTimeout(10000);
    client.setAutoReconnect(true);

    // set security features
    client.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.BASIC256_SIGN_ENCRYPT);


    // set endpoint configuration parameters
client.getEndpointConfiguration().setMaxByteStringLength(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    client.getEndpointConfiguration().setMaxArrayLength(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Also: do I have to name the certificates and/or their common name in a special way? 
I would be very happy if anybody could give me a hint as to what I need to do!

Comment: You haven't mentioned, but you are obviously using Prosys OPC UA Java SDK. I recommend that you ask the question again at the Prosys OPC Forum (https://forum.prosysopc.com), to get best support for your issues regarding that product.

Comment: Regarding the issue here, the main issues are that if you create the certificates yourself, you should 1. just initialise the ApplicationIdentity direct with those (look for the constructor), instead of using the loadOrCreate method; 2. make sure that the server trusts the issuer certificate that you use.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will ask my question there!